# Invalid Column name in SQL, but the value passing in is definitely correct?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using VB.NET and trying to get data from SQL database after I press the `PictureBox` and show the data in another windows with `.ShowDialog()`. The value passed in to the "show data form" is correct with the screenshot below, that I am passing the string "RAMEN".

[image: Press to see screenshot]

As we can see the variable foodName is `RAMEN` and in the sql command we can also see that it is correct which is `RAMEN`

But I'm getting an error that there is `Invalid column name` on the line `.ExecuteNonQuery`
Below is the screenshot of code and the error

[image: Screenshot of code with exception handle]

I am not sure what is wrong here, I am wondering whether is the sql command is not correct, or maybe the data type is wrong that I pass in. I have try sql command with VALUES...something but it is also not working.

Any solution for this kind of error? I'm sorry if I asked beginner question, because I just started to learn VB.NET with SQL database.

Comment: just by a glimpse, if `RAMEN` is a string it require `' '`

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as text and format it as code.

Comment: btw you can simply copy the command text and paste it in SQL to check if the query string correct or not

Comment: @T.Peter Alright, Sir i will always remember to put single quote with string from now on. HAHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is incorrect

You need to put single quote `'` between your `RAMEN`, cause the word `RAMEN` is considered as string in SQL Query

So you need to replace your code with this

```
cmd.CommantText = "SELECT * FROM food WHERE foodName '"& foodName &"'"
```

The easiest way to test if there's something wrong with your query is to just paste the query in SQL Server Management Studio or whatever DBMS you are using

Comment: Ok i got it, I forgot to put the single quote between the RAMEN. It works already. Thank you very much, Sir.

Comment: Alright Sir, I will try to use the SQL Server Management Studio to test the query, so sorry that i made little mistake here and there.

Comment: Not a problem, we all make mistakes